# O(n) + O(n^2) = O(n^2)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

We know thah O(n) + O(n) = O(n) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620993/on-on-on), even that O(n) + O(n) + ... + O(n)  = O(n^2) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449441/big-oh-how-can-on-on-on-be-equal-to-on2).

But what happend if O(n) + O(n^2)?

Is O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: Answer: ... yes

Comment: It would be `O(n^2+n)`.  Constants are dropped, but factors involving `n` should stay.

Comment: O(n²) is far larger than O(n) so obviously O(n + n²) can't be O(n)

Comment: @TimRoberts `O(n^2+n)` is equal to `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The *Big O* notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is used to understand the limit of a specific algorithm, and how fast its complexity grows. Therefore when considering the growth of a linear and a quadratic component of an algorithm, what remains in Big I notation is only the quadratic component.

As you can see from the attached image, the quadratic curve grows much faster (over y-axis) than the linear curve, determining the general tendency of the complexity for that algorithm to be just influenced by the quadratic curve, hence O(n^2).

The case for O(n) + O(n) = O(n) it's due to the fact that any constant in Big O notation can be discarded: in fact the curve y = n and y = 2n would be growing just as fast (although with a different slope).

The case for O(n) + ... + O(n) = O(n^2) it's not generally true! For this case the actual complexity would be polynomial with O(k*n). Only if the parameter k equals to the size of your input n, then you will end up with a specific quadratic case.

[image: Linear and quadratic function at comparison]